# Redis cache metrics with Prometheus(Spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, redis, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-data-redis

I am using RedisTemplate for caching purpose in my spring boot service. Now I want to check cache hit/cache miss  through end point actuator/prometheus. But can not see cache hit/cache miss for the cache.
The code I have written is something like below

```
    @EnableCaching
    @Configuration
    public class CachingConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
        public RedisTemplate<String, SomeData> redisTemplate(LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ObjectMapper objectMapper)                                                                               
 {
            RedisTemplate<String, SomeData> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
            template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    
            var valueSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<SomeData>(SomeData.class);
            valueSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
            template.setValueSerializer(valueSerializer);
    
            return template;
        }
    }
```

Now am doing like below to get and save into cache
to get:-

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
```

And to save:-

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, obj, some_time_limit);
```

My cache is working properly, am getting able to save into cache and getting proper data.
But I don't see cache hit/miss related data inside actuator/prometheus.
In my application.yml file I have added below

```
cache:
    redis:
      enable-statistics: 'true'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that in order for `Springboot Cache Monitoring` to apply (Including Hits/Misses), you would need to depend on `AutoConfiguration`.

In your case you are creating the RedisTemplate yourself, and probably enable-statistics is not actually applied.

Can you remove the redistemplate creation and use `@Cacheable` annotation abstraction? That way any supported Cache library will work out of the box, without you having to create `@Bean` and manually configuring it.

Otherwise, generally if you wanted to enable statistics on a cache manager manually, you will need to call `RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder  enableStatistics()`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.html

For Reference:

> Auto-configuration enables the instrumentation of all available Cache
> instances on startup, with metrics prefixed with cache. Cache
> instrumentation is standardized for a basic set of metrics.
> Additional, cache-specific metrics are also available.
>
> Metrics are tagged by the name of the cache and by the name of the
> CacheManager, which is derived from the bean name.

> Only caches that are configured on startup are bound to the registry. For caches not
> defined in the cache’s configuration, such as caches created on the
> fly or programmatically after the startup phase, an explicit
> registration is required. A CacheMetricsRegistrar bean is made
> available to make that process easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same question and spent a good number of hours trying to figure out how to enable cache metrics for my manually created `RedisTemplate` instance.
What I eventually realised is that it's only `RedisCache` class which collects and exposes `CacheStatistics` through `getStatistics()` method. As far as I can see there is nothing like that for `RedisTemplate`, which means you either need to switch to using `RedisCache` through `RedisCacheManager` and `@Cacheable` annotation or implement your custom metrics collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in my application (as you can see it is unaware of any RedisCache, just plain spring abstraction):

```
@Configuration
class EnableCacheMetrics(
    val cacheMetricsRegistrar: CacheMetricsRegistrar,
    val cacheManager: CacheManager
) {
    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent::class)
    fun addCachesToMetrics() {
        cacheMetricsRegistrar.bindCacheToRegistry(cacheManager.getCache("foo"))
        cacheMetricsRegistrar.bindCacheToRegistry(cacheManager.getCache("bar"))
    }
}
```

"foo" and "bar" are caches created dynamically via @Cachable. My cache statistics are visible via /actuator/metrics and /actuator/prometheus.